# THandle of File in MemoryStream (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe8

I have a file loaded in a memorystream and want to get the filehandle of it without saving the file on the harddisk.

I can't figure out how to do it.

It should return the same result as CreateFile does.

```
  myFile:= CreateFile('myfile.exe', GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ...
```

I tried it with the Memory attribute of memorystream but it doesn't return the same handle as CreateFile

```
  mem_stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  mem_stream.LoadFromFile('myfile.exe');
  mem_hFile := mem_stream.Memory;
  Writeln(Format('mem_hFile: %d', [mem_hFile]));
  mem_stream.Free;
```

Comment: `TMemoryStream` doesn't have a file handle, and clearly `Memory` is a pointer to the block of memory that the stream represents and not a file handle. It's not clear what you're trying to do, because to obtain a file handle you need a file (that's why it's called a **file handle**).

Comment: @KenWhite i have a file loaded in stream and want to get the handle like CreateFile.

Comment: You should to learn more what is **file handle** exactly. The file handle is not persistent for the file itself. It generated each time when you open the file and will be different at another time when you open that the same file. If of course I understood right what are you mean.

Comment: The `TMemoryStream.LoadFromFile` method loads the file into the memory block pointed by the `Memory` property and closes the file, so there is no file handle available during the lifetime of the memory stream object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a file loaded in a memorystream and want to get the filehandle of it without saving the file on the harddisk.

There is no file handle in `TMemoryStream`.  What you have done is load a *copy* of the file's bytes into a block of memory.  The `TMemoryStream.Memory` property returns a pointer to that memory block.

> It should return the same result as CreateFile does.

Then you have to actually call `CreateFile()`, either directly or indirectly, such as with a `TFileStream`:

```
fs_stream := TFileStream.Create('myfile.exe', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
fs_hFile := fs_stream.Handle; // <-- returns the HANDLE from CreateFile()
...
fs_stream.Free;
```

Answer (score 4):

A memory stream has no file handle associated with it. You cannot use a memory stream with any function that expects a file handle.

Whatever your problem is, getting a file handle from a memory stream is, by dint of being impossible, not the solution.

You also seem to have a misunderstanding about the numeric values of handles. You cannot compare the numeric values of two handles and expect them to be the same value if the handles refer to the same object. Two distinct file handles have different numeric value, even if they refer to the same value.